# ¿Como cambiar el action=" " de un form?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un problema y quisiera saber si me pueden dar una mano.
He intentado cambiar mi action=" " de un form.
He intentado bastante codigo pero aun no logro el resultado.
¿Que intento realizar?
el action se va de la siguiente manera :

```
<form action="reporteria/mipdf.php" align="right" target="reporte" method="POST" >
          <SELECT name="mes">
          <OPTION>selecciona el mes</OPTION>                               
          <OPTION value="01">ENERO</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="02">FEBRERO</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="03">MARZO</OPTION>...
          <INPUT type="submit" value="buscar">
        </form>
```

El codigo anterior lo que hace es que me redirecciona hacia mipdf.php.
El asunto es que a mi me gustaria cambiar el "reporteria/mipdf.php" por lo que contenga otro valor de otro select, es decir:

```
<form action="X.php" align="right" target="reporte" method="POST" >
              <SELECT name="tiporeporte">
          <OPTION>Selecciona que pdf quieres</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf1.php">MiPDF1</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf2.php">MiPDF2</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf3.php">MiPDF3</OPTION>
          </SELECT>
```

Si alguien fuera muy amable, le agradeceria muchisimo que me diera una mano! Muchisimas gracias ante mano!

EDITADO:
Anexo el codigo .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
 require_once 'validar.php';
?> 
<html lang = "es">
 <head>
  <title>Mipagina</title>
  <meta charset = "utf-8" />
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/logopu.png" type="image/x-icon">
 </head>
 <body>
<?php include_once "menu/header.php";?>
   <div id="contenedor">
   <div id="cargando"></div>
   <div id='contenido' style="margin-top:60px">
   <div>
     <form action="reportes/mipdf1.php" align="right" target="reporte" method="POST">
     <SELECT name="tiporeporte">
     <OPTION>Selecciona que pdf quieres</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf1.php">MiPDF1</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf2.php">MiPDF2</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf3.php">MiPDF3</OPTION>
     </SELECT> 
     <SELECT name="mes">
     <OPTION>Selecciona el mes</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="01">ENERO</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="02">FEBRERO</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="03">MARZO</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="04">ABRIL</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="05">MAYO</OPTION>
     </SELECT>
   <INPUT type="submit" value="ir">
   </form>
     </div>
       <iframe width="83%" height="585" name="reporte" src=""></iframe>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php include_once "menu/footer.php";?>
 </body>
 <script src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src = "js/login.js"></script>
 <script src = "js/sidebar.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo unico que debes hacer es capturar el evento change del select que va a determinar el action del form, y en dicho evento haces el cambio.

**Te dejo un ejemplo:**

```js
function changeAction(val){
   $("#form1").attr("action",val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="reporteria/mipdf.php" align="right" target="reporte" method="POST" >
          ...
           ...
 </form>

<SELECT name="tiporeporte" onchange="changeAction(this.value);">
          <OPTION>Selecciona que pdf quieres</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf1.php">MiPDF1</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf2.php">MiPDF2</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="reporteria/pdf3.php">MiPDF3</OPTION>
          </SELECT>


<button onclick="console.log($('#form1').attr('action'))">Mostrar valor de action</button>
```

Comment: No me funcionó, se llama a el mismo. :(

Comment: En el código Javascript, debes agregar el numeral antes de form1. De esta forma: `$("#form1")attr("action",val);`

Comment: Poniendole ni el #, funciona.. :(

Comment: También tienes que agregar un punto antes del attr: `$("#form1").attr("action",val);`

Comment: Ahi modifique la respuesta. Perdon por los errores, es la hora :( (2:50 am Argentina)

Comment: ¡Solucionado! ¡Muchas Gracias a todos!

Comment: @Christian no modifiques la respuesta de quien te respondió, eso no es bien visto en la comunidad, deja que el haga los cambios necesarios; si lo haces tu se considera vandalismo