# Enviar respuesta de API por URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario en la ruta `/solicitud.html`. Cuando una persona llena el formulario, envío mediante POST estos datos a mi servidor. En mi servidor proceso esos datos y retorno una respuesta. Si `response.result == "OK"` Entonces quiero dirigir a `/solicitudEvaluacion.html` y mostrar un msj que diga "Gracias, hemos recibido tu solicitud".
Ahora, si `response.result != "OK"` quiero dirigir a `/solicitudEvaluacion.html` y mostrar un msj que diga "Su solicitud a quedado rechazada ya que su situacion es `response.situacion`".

Mi idea es enviar a `response.situacion` en la URL de la siguiente manera:

```
window.location.replace('https://miurl.com/solicitudEvaluacion.html?situacion=' + response.situacion);
```

Los  `window.location.replace` No están funcionando y siempre dirigen a `/solicitudEvaluacion.html` que es el que se encuentra en el `<form action="solicitudEvaluacion.html">`
Como puedo hacer para direccionar a `/solicitudEvaluacion.html` pero con parámetros?

```js
let nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;
let apellido = document.querySelector("#apellido").value;
var settings = {
  url: "https://miurl.com/solicitud",
  method: "POST",
  async: false,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    nom: nombre,
    ape: apellido,
  }),
}

;
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

    if (response.result == "OK") {
      window.location.replace('https://miurl.com/solicitudEvaluacion.html?situacion=OK');
    } else {
      window.location.replace('https://miurl.com/solicitudEvaluacion.html?situacion=' + response.situacion);
    }
  }
  

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="needs-validation" action="solicitudEvaluacion.html" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
      </div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
      </div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">

      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: En tu codigo no veo que estes haciendo referencia al altributo que va a cambiar en el formulario desde javascript, podrias ver si esta respuesta te ayuda a orientarte? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/211409/como-cambiar-el-action-de-un-form

Comment: Es que en el formulario no va a cambiar nada, lo que busco es direccionar a otra pagina con parámetros diferentes en la URL.

Comment: Pero es que entendiendo la logica de tu codigo: escribo mi nombre y apellido, con esto hago un envio, ¿por medio de que?, ¿POST?, esto deberia devolver una respuesta del servidor, ¿sabes si realmente te esta dando una respuesta?, entonces, si te da una respuesta vas a enviar al usuario a la misma url, pero con unos parametros añadidos a la url ```?situacion= SITUACION``` ¿podrias editar la respuesta indicando mas o menos como deberia ser el resultado?, y ¿despues de eso que?

Comment: La lógica es así, el cliente llena el formulario de 10 campos. Envió esa información mediante POST a mi servidor, consulto en mi Base de datos la situación de esa persona,  y la retorno. Si `response.result == "OK"` dirijo a `/solicitudEvaluacion.html` (Que no es la misma URL del formulario) , mostrando un msj de, Gracias por su solicitud. Ahora si `response.result != "OK `. Necesito dirigir a `/solicitudEvaluacion.html` pero con la situación de la persona. Y mostrar un msj "Su solicitud esta rechazada ya que su situacion es:

Comment: Ok, ya entiendo, pero en primera, en tu formulario no estas indicando por medio de que estas enviando los datos, podrias verificar si con tu codigo actual estas recibiendo la respuesta que esperas?

Comment: Los envío a traves de ajax, y si, estoy recibiendo la respuesta que quiero. response.result es igual a "OK". El problema al parecer es que no se puede redireccionar dentro de un form.

Comment: Si pruebas con un ```location.href```? al obtener la respuesta indicada, entonces le dices desde el script que te redireccione con ```location.ref="mipagina.php?situacion=SITUACION"``` en ves de location.replace

Answer (score -1):

Actualizo respuesta después de leer el hilo.
Aún no entiendo como llamas tu código pero para responder rápido, si `location.replace` o `location.href` no se comportan como esperas, te doy un hack: crea un tag `a`, asigna como propiedad `href="el-url-con-query"` y clickéalo.
Además, estoy usando encodeURI asumiendo que la respuesta puede venir con espacios.

```javascript
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  const query = response.result == 'OK' ? 'OK' : encodeURI(response.situacion);
  const tag = document.createElement('a');
  tag.href = `https://miurl.com/solicitudEvaluacion.html?situacion=${query}`;
  tag.click();
}
```

Dime como te va, saludos!

---

Respuesta anterior

En tu código no indicas cómo realizas el `submit` del formulario, por lo que concluyo no escribiste todo tu código y utilizas un botón.

De ser el caso, verifica que dicho botón sea:

```html
<button type="button" ... />
```

En lugar de

```html
<button type="submit" .../>
```

Ya que de ser el caso, tu `action` está enviando la solicitud sin `Query`.
Si no es así, escribe el código completo por favor.